# How to create a collection with (template) iterator values?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I want to have a collection (list, vector, map etc.) of iterators, but the code doesn't work:

```
template <class T>
class A
{
    std::list<std::unordered_map<int, T>::iterator> l; //doesn't compile
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<T>::iterator> um; //doesn't compile
    std::vector<std::list<T>::iterator> v; //doesn't compile either
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`iterator` is a [dependent name](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name), you need to qualify it with the `typename` keyword:

```
std::list<typename std::unordered_map<int, T>::iterator> l;
          ^^^^^^^^
std::unordered_map<int, typename std::vector<T>::iterator> um;
                        ^^^^^^^^
std::vector<typename std::list<T>::iterator> v;
            ^^^^^^^^
```